# HTML5 Geolocation not working in Android Emulator

Tags: android, html, android-emulator, geolocation

I am facing a strange issue wherein HTML5 Geolocation is not working only on Android Emulator.  I have a very simple code as follows:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(suc, locFail, { 'enableHighAccuracy': true, 'timeout': 60000, 'maximumAge': 60000 });
```

Once the emulator is running I do supply mock coordinates using DDMS/telnet geo fix.

But the moment it executes the above line of code, the emulator hangs. In LogCat I get messages notifying that each service is dying and then I get the Android Emulator Launch screen. I cannot do anything with the emulator except closing it and restarting it.

Version of Android: 2.3.3
ADT Version: 20

Emulator Settings: Allow mock locations is enabled. Use GPS Satellites is enabled.

The same code works perfectly fine on my desktop browser.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an AVD, you will see two versions. For e.g. The Target names for 2.3.3 will be Android 2.3.3 and Google APIs (Google Inc). Try selecting the Google APIs version for your AVD and see if it works.

Comment: It works if I change my AVD target to Google APIs. This is really strange. In either case I get an error in my LogCat "Unable to open GPS config file /etc/gps.conf.

Comment: I have seen this happening with the 2.3.3 Android AVD, which for some reason does not get the mock co-ordinates whereas its Google API version gets. Hence I suggested that you try it. Glad to know that works for now.

Comment: Thanks. But I think Google Maps 2.3.3 AVD is the hero :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to move to the Google Maps version of the AVD and see if you are able to see the mock locations.

Comment: Where can I find Google Maps app in the AVD. I tried looking at all apps, but could not find Google Maps.